# Question on Reply Mail Management

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am dealing with Reply Mail Management, but there few things i am not to get :

1. What is the role of the sub domain? I am not getting the fair idea from help portal.
2. Can the reply email address be assigned as a different email address like Example@gmail.com?

Please provide some details on Reply Subdomain and how it is linked with Email Reply Address.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities regarding Email reply address:
1. In the RMM settings you can add an email with a different username, but the same domain that you registered in DNS records eg. xxxx@customerbrand.com. The email will be forwarded to the Routing email address that you must add.
2. In the custom RMM inside the sender profile settings you can add a completely different email address eg. xxxxx@gmail.com

In both cases the customer will not see the RMM address, but xxxx@ + a token used to recognize the Reply for a specific send and subscriber.